# How do I create a RAID5 at installation of Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, 12.10, raid

For the life of me I cannot find the way to create a RAID 5 set while doing a clean install of ubuntu 12.10.  It appears the "Alternate" installation disk either doesn't exist or I am looking in the wrong place.  That was the way I have done this on older versions of Ubuntu.  I can do an isntallation of 12.04 and upgrade to 12.10, but that seems so unclean and defeats the purpose of the clean installation.

These are new disks (5 x 1 TB) so data preservation is not an issue.
Any help on doing this cleanly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I failed to mention this is Ubuntu Desktop 12.10, 64-bit.  The RAID is a software RAID and no "FakeRAID" or port multiplier.  All drives are plugged into the motherboard's built-in AHCI controller.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Ubuntu Server, but hopefully these will apply:
https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html
http://forevergeeks.com/setup-ubuntu-server-with-raid-5/

Edit: One idea is that you could install Ubuntu Server as shown in the links above, and then install the desktop packages afterwards.

Edit 2: Read this: http://news.softpedia.com/news/Canonical-Drops-Alternate-CDs-from-Ubuntu-12-10-289338.shtml It addresses your problem.